# Need help setting up data model to display tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I had my tableView populating as it should for a little while but then made some tweaks to how I get my data from Parse and since then I can't get my tableView to display without crashing with **fatal error: Array index out of range**
Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
var vaccineEntry: Array<Array<Dictionary<String,String>>> = [[
    ["name" : "Rabies 1-yr", "detail": "None"],
    ["name" : "Rabies 3-yr", "detail": "None"],
    ["name" : "Distemper", "detail": "None"],
    ["name" : "Parvovirus", "detail": "None"],
    ["name" : "Adenovirus", "detail": "None"]],
  [
    ["name" : "Parainfluenza", "detail": "None"],
    ["name" : "Bordetella", "detail": "None"],
    ["name" : "Lyme Disease", "detail": "None"],
    ["name" : "Leptospirosis", "detail": "None"],
    ["name" : "Canine Influenza", "detail": "None"]
  ]]

var sections = ["Core Vaccines", "Non-Core Vaccines"]
var titles = [["Rabies 1-yr", "Rabies 3-yr", "Distemper", "Parvovirus", "Adenovirus"], ["Parainfluenza", "Bordetella", "Lyme Disease", "Leptospirosis", "Canine Influenza"]]


var textCellIdenifier = "vaccineCell"

// Section Headers
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

    return self.sections[section]
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return self.sections.count

}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

return self.titles[section].count
}




func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdenifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    let object = vaccineEntry[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = object["name"]
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = object["detail"]


    return cell
}
}
```

This line crashes with the fatal error:

```
let object = vaccineEntry[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
```

Or I can not make an object variable and just go:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = vaccineEntry[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]["name"]
cell.textLabel?.text = vaccineEntry[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]["detail"]
```

But same deal, just crashes on the ["name"] line. What am I doing wrong? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: so your data only has name and details

Answer (score 0):

Works perfectly fine for me without any errors or warnings!
PFB the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var vaccineEntry: Array<Array<Dictionary<String,String>>> = [[
    ["name" : "Rabies 1-yr", "detail": "None"],
    ["name" : "Rabies 3-yr", "detail": "None"],
    ["name" : "Distemper", "detail": "None"],
    ["name" : "Parvovirus", "detail": "None"],
    ["name" : "Adenovirus", "detail": "None"]],
    [
        ["name" : "Parainfluenza", "detail": "None"],
        ["name" : "Bordetella", "detail": "None"],
        ["name" : "Lyme Disease", "detail": "None"],
        ["name" : "Leptospirosis", "detail": "None"],
        ["name" : "Canine Influenza", "detail": "None"]
    ]]

var sections = ["Core Vaccines", "Non-Core Vaccines"]
var titles = [["Rabies 1-yr", "Rabies 3-yr", "Distemper", "Parvovirus", "Adenovirus"], ["Parainfluenza", "Bordetella", "Lyme Disease", "Leptospirosis", "Canine Influenza"]]


var textCellIdenifier = "vaccineCell"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: self.textCellIdenifier)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return self.sections[section]
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.sections.count
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.titles[section].count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdenifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    let object = vaccineEntry[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = object["name"]
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = object["detail"]

    return cell
}

}
```

The running code on simulator:

[image: your view]

Comment: But its not showing the details, which above are just the text "None" for each of the titles.. I have found a solution that actually has made my code run faster below.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the work-around that made the code simpler and work better!

```
var sections = ["Core Dog Vaccines", "Non-Core Dog Vaccines"]
var titles = [["Rabies 1-yr", "Rabies 3-yr", "Distemper", "Parvovirus", "Adenovirus"], ["Parainfluenza", "Bordetella", "Lyme Disease", "Leptospirosis", "Canine Influenza"]]
var details = [["No Dogument", "No Dogument", "No Dogument", "No Dogument", "No Dogument"], ["No Dogument", "No Dogument", "No Dogument", "No Dogument", "No Dogument"]]

var textCellIdenifier = "vaccineCell"


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdenifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell


    cell.textLabel?.text = self.titles[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = self.details[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]


    return cell
}
```

Instead of having a complicated Array< Array< Dictionary< String,String>>> I just made a separate array for the details.. Ugh making it complicated to begin with sucks but still learning everyday! Now I can load data from parse like so:

```
let rabies1Query = PFQuery(className: "Vaccine")
    rabies1Query.whereKey("userId", equalTo: (PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId)!)
    rabies1Query.whereKey("newID", equalTo: self.dogObject)
    rabies1Query.whereKey("vaccineType", equalTo: "Rabies 1-yr")
    rabies1Query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (object, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if let object = object {
                for object in object {

                    if object["expired"] as! Bool == true {
                        self.details[0][0] = self.expired
                        print("printing rabies 1-yr - EXPIRED")

                    } else if object["expired"] as! Bool == false {
                        self.details[0][0] = self.upToDate
                        print("printing rabies 1-yr - UP TO DATE")
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("printing rabies 1-yr - No Document")
        }
    })
```

And so on for each title changing the location of the details array location. Hope someone else can see and learn something!